# Does there exist a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_na_n^k$ converges for $k=1$ but diverges for every other odd positive integer?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, contest-math

Does there exist a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_na_n^k$ converges for $k=1$ but diverges for every other odd positive integer?

Comment: Note that since $\sum_n a_n$ converges, we have $\vert a_n \vert < 1$ for $n>N$. From this $N$ on, we have $\vert a_n \vert^k < \vert a_n \vert$

Comment: I believe not. For k=1, the sum converges and $a_n=o(\frac{1}{n})$. For $k>1$ odd, this is $o(\frac{1}{n^k})$ and converges.

Comment: @Marvis I guess that can be made into an answer.

Comment: @CBenni: Where does $a_n=o\left(\cfrac{1}{n}\right)$ come from?

Comment: @xavierm02 you can show that the sum over every sequence that is asymptotically bigger or equal to 1/n and with a finite number of sign switches diverges and converges otherwise. My comment was effectively the same as Marvis' anyways

Answer (score 7):

Yes. In fact, a stronger fact holds:

> For any set $C$ (finite or infinite) of odd positive integers, there is a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that for $k$ odd, 
>    $$ \sum_n a_n^k $$
>   converges iff $k\in C$.

Whether this is possible was asked by Polya as problem 4142 in the American Mathematical Monthly. It was solved by N.J. Fine, the solution appeared in 1946 (pp 283-284), and can be found [here](http://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/fine-soltopolya.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer. If $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, no such series exists.  Since $\sum_n a_n < \infty$, $a_n \to 0$.  For $n$ sufficiently large, $a_n < 1$, so $a_n^k < a_n < 1$.  This shows that $\sum_n a_n^k$ converges for any $k > 1$.
In fact this applies if the series is absolutely convergent.

You would need a mighty strange conditionally convergent series to meet your criterion.

Comment: interesting.  We know where to begin to look.