# Is there a sequence of real numbers so that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n^p$ convergent iff $p$ prime?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Is there  a real sequence $(x_n)$ such that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n^p$$ convergent if and only if $p$ is **prime** ?
If the answer is YES, can we find an **explicit formula** for $x_n$ ?

What happens if we ask the similar questions about a complex sequence $(z_n)$ and the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {z_n}^p \,\,?$$

Comment: Are your numbers $x_n$ positive? If so, the convergence of $\sum x_n^p$ implies the convergence of $\sum x_n^a$ for all $a\ge p$.

Comment: @orangeskid: They can be negative.

Comment: You have posed an interesting question. Even if the even exponent sinks it, the odd exponents are not a clear thing for $x_n$ real, and for $x_n$ complex it's not yet clear.

Comment: @orangeskid the odds are also easy, I just omitted them since it wasn't asked. You can see the edited answer below.

Comment: And to both of you:  I'm reverting to the original question so as not to confuse new readers, if you're further interested in the much more complicated case of complex w/o the bars, you should consider asking it as a separate question while linking this one.

Comment: One thing you can have is a sequence $x_n$ of real numbers such that, for $m$ an *odd* positive integer, $\sum_n x_n^m$ converges iff $m$ is prime. (This has been discussed here before. I'll add a link if I find it.)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/288433/462).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thank you. I got it. +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely not, for if $\sum |z_n|^p$ converges, then we know that for all $n>N$, some fixed integer, we have $|z_n|<1$, but then $\sum |z_n|^{p+1}$ converges by comparison test, indeed, $\sum |z_n|^k$ converges for all $k>p$.

Even if you only had conditional convergence for the real case (or the complex one without the absolute values) it would be false, for we can choose $p=2$ and reduce to the case of a positive series, then repeat the argument from $|z_n|$ noting now all $p>2$ converge absolutely since we have absolute convergence for $p=2$.

**Edit** I think I'm a bit reticent to stick on the odds, actually, the dilation reduction in my induction relies on the idea that expanding all the terms will expand the sum, but that's not necessarily true.

Comment: Oh. Nice+1 & Thank you. What about real case?

Comment: @Nilan I've edited the answer, there's just no hope of saving it. The primes don't have the right kind of properties to be determined by series like that.

Comment: If I stick on odd prime?

Comment: @Nilan I'm actually going to retract that last bit about odd primes, it's true I can take out the dilation factors from individual terms, but in order to get the inequality for the estimate I need that this shrinks the entire sum, which may or may not be true.

Comment: I am very confused as to why someone has downvoted me. If you find something wrong, please comment.

Comment: Thank you Adam Hughes. Also I did not down vote for your answer. Because it helps me to understand, some parts of my question is wrong.